# Using beautifulsoup to get multiple tags and attributes data

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to use beautifulsoup to get multiple tags and attributes from following HTML

1)div id= home_1039509

2)div id="guest_1039509

3)id="odds_3_1039509

4)id="gs_1039509

5)id="hs_1039509

6)id="time_1039509

HTML:

```
  <tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1039509" bgcolor="#F7F3F7" index="0">
    <td width="10">
       <img src="images/lclose.gif" onclick="hidematch(0)" style="cursor:pointer;">
    </td>
  <td width="63" bgcolor="#d15023">
    <font color="#ffffff">U18<br>
       <span id="t_1039509">14:05</span>
    </font>
  </td>
  <td width="115" style="text-align:left;">
  <div id="home_1039509">
       <a href="javascript:Team(19195)">U18()</a>
  </div>
  <div class="oddsAns"> 
       &nbsp;[
  <a href="javascript:AsianOdds('1039509')">A</a>
   -
  <a href="javascript:EuropeOdds(1039509)" target="_self">B</a>
   -
  </div>
 <div id="guest_1039509">
  <a href="javascript:Team(11013)">U18</a>
 </div>
 </td>
 <td width="30">
     <div id="gs_1039509" class="score">2</div>
 <div id="time_1039509">
     42
     <img src="images/in.gif" border="0">
 </div>
 <div id="hs_1039509" class="score">1</div></td>
 <td width="90" id="odds_1_1039509" title=""></td>
 <td width="90" id="odds_4_1039509" title=""></td>
 <td width="90" id="odds_3_1039509" title="">
     <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">0.94</a>                            
 <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
     <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">2.5/3</a>            
   <br>
     0.86
 </td>
 <td width="90" id="odds_31_1039509" title="nothing"></td>
    </tr>
```

Code:

```
rows = table.findAll("tr", {"id" : re.compile('tr_*\d')})

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll("span", {"id" : re.compile('t_*\d')}) &
    cols = tr.findAll("div", {"id" : re.compile('home_*\d')}) &
    cols = tr.findAll("span", {"id" : re.compile('guest_*\d')}) &
    cols = tr.findAll("span", {"id" : re.compile('guest_*\d')}) &
    cols = tr.findAll("span", {"id" : re.compile('odds_3_*\d')}) &
    cols = tr.findAll("span", {"id" : re.compile('hs_*\d')})

for td in cols:
    t = td.find(text=True)
    if t:
        text = t + ';' # concat
    print text,
print
```

Comment: This is just as bad a question as when you were called `rfvtgb2014`. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code?

Comment: my code is not work,and seeking advise, thx !

Comment: *"my code is [sic] not work"* is **not** a useful problem statement. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? What have **you** done to try to fix it so far?

Comment: The question is not completely bad: at least it contains the code, the input and what the user is trying to achieve - this helps to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass [a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and check if `id` [starts with](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) `home_`, `guest_` etc:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = lambda x: x and x.startswith(('home_', 'guest_', 'odds_', 'gs_', 'hs_', 'time_'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'))
print [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in soup.find_all(id=f)]
```

prints:

```
[u'U18()', u'U18', u'2', u'42', u'1', u'', u'', u'0.942.5/30.86', u'']
```

Note that `startswith()` allows to pass a tuple of strings to check.

Comment: @hknothin2014 For further information about how BeutifulSoup works check the documentation http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of **cols** like

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find_all(["div", "span"], id=re.compile('[home|guest|odds_3|gs|hs|time]_\d+'))
```

regex above just an example

In your case it can be

```
cols = tr.find_all(["div", "span"], id=re.compile('[home|guest|odds|gs|hs|time]_\d+'))

for tag in cols:
    # find(text=True) only returns data if immediate node has text
    # incase <div><span>123</span></div> will return None
    t = td.find_all(text=True)
    if t:
        # find_all will return list so need to join
        text = ''.join(t).strip() + ';'
    print(text)
```

Comment: thanks, but cannot get the data within <td width="90" id="odds_3_1039509" title=""> tag, please help, thanks a lot !

Comment: it is because find is selecting from div and span elements only ["div", "span", "td"] will select td

Comment: thanks, actually I added ["div", "span", "td"] , but it still not work, I don't know what the reason, thanks !

Comment: you need to update the regex , may be this helps  re.compile(r'[home|guest|odds|gs|hs|time]_\d+')

Comment: even I write cols = tr.findAll("td", {"id" : odds_3_1039509) but it still cannot get the data

Comment: three data inside td id="odds_3_1039509" tag a)0.94 b)2.5/3 c)0.86